# Problems with zooming and mouse events in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I'm having trouble with everything mouse related for an Openlayers map when the map is placed inside a DIV with position fixed. The map works fine when you're at the top of the viewport of the browser, but when you're scrolling down the page, you can see that the zooming/click effects are shifted. You can check here http://41.32.148.178:82/#!search=KFC%2F0%2F0%2F0%2F%2F to see exactly what I mean.

This guys seems like he's facing the same problem but didn't get any responses http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-users/2010-July/018769.html

Comment: I am not seeing the effect you are talking about -- seems normal after scrolling.  What browser and version are you using to view it?  What operating system?  How far do you scroll down before this occurs?

Comment: i'm using the latest version of chrome, but this actually happens on all other browsers, when you open the url above the zooming works fine, but try to scroll down the page using the scroll bar, then try to zoom again, you'll notice that the map zooms in to the wrong location

Comment: i am not seeing this problem in FF 9.0.1.  Do you mean that if you press the little up arrow about the scale zoom area, instead of moving up, the map moves down?  If not, then I am not finding anything unusual.

Comment: nop, i mean when you scroll down the page using the browser scrollbar, and then you try to interact with the map using double clicks for example to zoom in, the map zooms in to a different location

Comment: Sorry, I am not seeing the problem from my end.  Anyone else?

Comment: Yup, it's really easy to reproduce, just create a div containing openlayers map and make it draggable (jquery easydrag plugin for instance).  Then just move the div to the left/right, then try to zoom in the map, it's being offset.  I still have this happening to me after almost year since this SO post.   I used to have a google map in that did not have that problem which makes it an openlayers issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in the OpenLayers version I was using (2.1), I updated to the latest version(2.11) and everything works fine now, thanks.

Comment: can you provide details about this bug or link to the bug report? so others can also get help on this problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to adjust the position of the map based on the vertical and horizental scollbar values.

For firefox, chrome, safari, opera use this code to get scrollbar values

```
window.pageXOffset
window.pageYOffset
```

while for ie use this

```
document.body.scrollLeft
document.body.scrollTop
```

see examples here

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_pagexoffset.asp